# Create $ angular service to inject in other components

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular and I need to define routing in ng-route config but also in my services to be used by $http in services methods.

The problem is that the route strings change in my application according to language ... For example for an about us page I might have:

```
"en/about-us", "pt/quem-somos", "fr/ ..."
```

The application has a RouteProvider that returns route strings by key.

The idea would be to create a script on the fly for a service that injected in angular components would allow to get those routes strings.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Create $routes service using backend code ...

</script>
```

This would be used on app.config as follows:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $routes) {

    $routeProvider.
      when($routes.getByKey('about.home', {
      templateUrl: 'about/home.html',
      controller: 'AboutController'
    })
}
```

But also in a service as follows:

```
application.service('CountryService', function ($http, $routes) {

  return {

    GetList: function () {
      return $http.get($routes.getByKey('api.countries.list');
    }

  }

});
```

My problem is how to write the JS part of such a service and to plug it into angular components. Is it possible to create such a service?

Comment: Not totally sure I understand the question but could you just make an ajax call in your app.config function to get the dynamic routes from the back end and then call the $routeProvider

Comment: The question is how to get those localized routes into my angular code config ... An ajax call to a backend endpoint would be an option. But I use these routes not only in app.config but also in each service: GetList: function () { return $http.get('api/countries'); } ... How would I solve that in this case?

Comment: @jw56578 I just added some extra information on my question regarding the services ...

Comment: depends on your backend.  actually best thing you can do is.  write a javascript function to generate routes independent then angularjs.  this way you can inject it anywhere & anytime.  think out of the box.

Comment: I am using ASP.NET MVC ... Yes, but I think what you described is my question ... I mean in my ASP.NET MVC views I am using C# code to generate javascript code. The JS code would be a function that returns a Route String based on a Key String. And then I would inject that funcion as a service $routes into any component of my angular application, config or services, to get the routes. My question is how to create this JS part?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/how-to-defer-route-definition-in-an-angularjs-web-app

Comment: Yes and no ... That solution seems to care only about routes that has a template a controller  while i also need the routes that call the API and are used in the services ... Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I would not conflate view routes from the API endpoints - these are different creatures.

And you don't need to create a route per language - just use language as a parameter:

```
$routeProvider
  .when("/:lang/about-us", {
    template: "<h3>About Us</h3> in lang: {{language}}",
    controller: function($scope, $routeParams, $location){
      $scope.language = $routeParams.lang;
    }
  })
  .when("/:lang/something-else", {
    template: "<h3>Something Else</h3> in lang: {{language}}",
    controller: function($scope, $routeParams){
      $scope.language = $routeParams.lang;
    }
  })
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vZx73Lui3mW772poFjTz?p=preview)